# Using LINQ to extract Atrributes from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've got a XML file and I'm trying to extract some information from The file has a list of products and their attributes. I'm trying to create 3D models for Tekla so only some of these attributes are relevant to me. 
The intern before me was doing this manually. My issue is that there are 10 files and each file is over 100MB large. I'm not interested in wasting a significant portion of my existence sifting through over 1 million lines of code. Here's a basic setup of each Product entry in the Xml file.

```
  <Product ID="productID" UserTypeID="USERTYPE">
    <Name>PRODUCT NAME</Name>
      <ClassificationReference ClassificationID=" CLASSIFICATION_PARKING"  Type="LINK_TYPE_CLASSIFICATION_SYSTEM"/>

    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_STREETPRICE_STD_NETAMOUNT">0.00</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_SAP_MATMAS_WERKS">0000</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_STREETPRICE_STD_CURRENCY">EUR</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_SAP_MATMAS_ZZPUBLISH">00000</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_SAP_MATMAS_ZZCATALOG_TYPE">00000</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_SAP_MATMAS_MARM_PCE_MEINH">0000</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_STREETPRICE_STD_QUANTITY">1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_SAP_MATMAS_MARM_PCE_UMREZ">1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_SAP_MATMAS_ZZDISCGRP">000000</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="CHA_STREETPRICE_STD_NETPRICE">0.00</Value> 
    </Values>
  </Product>
```

I've only just discovered LINQ but I think it might be able to help me here. My problem is I only seem to know the basics of LINQ and XML. I've got a basic approach in my head but I'm not quite sure how to write the queries. 
Here's what I'm thinking:

I only need products of certain `USERTYPE` so I'd ignore all Product Elements without that `USERTYPE`

Then I'd like to extract the Product attributes "ID" and "USERTYPE" together with the `Name` Node.

Then extract the Values in the `Values` Node based on the `attributeID`. I don't want all attributes just some.

Write to a text file on a single line.
However, I've stumbled at the first step. I've got this query:

```
// find Products with USERTYPE "PRD"    

  static IEnumerable<string>GetKeyWordNames(string file)
            {
                return XDocument.Load(file)
                    .Descendants("Product")
                    .Attributes("ID")      // how do you write a query to select multiple attributes
                    .Select(attr => attr.Value)
                    .ToList();
            }
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
if(Attributes[0] == "ID"&& Attributes[1].Value = "thisValue")
select(product);
```

Unfortunately I'm not quite sure how to achieve this with LINQ.
So my questions in short are:

How do I query multiple attributes and only select a product based on attribute type?

How do I query `Values` nodes based on `AttributeID`. Is `Values` a descendant of `Product` or an innerNode?

How do I stored said results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood your question this is what you want (except the `AttributeId` attribute present in Values):-

> I only need products of certain USERTYPE so I'd ignore all Product
>   Elements without that USERTYPE

You need to filter the data so you need a `.Where` method.

After this all we are doing is projecting the elements present inside product node.

```
List<Product> result = xdoc.Descendants("Product")
                           .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("UserTypeID") == "1")
                           .Select(x => new Product
                           {
                              ProductId = (string)x.Attribute("ID"),
                              UserTypeID = (string)x.Attribute("UserTypeID"),
                              ProductName = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                              ValuesIds = x.Descendants("Value")
                                         .Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("AttributeID"))
                                         .ToList()
                           }).ToList();
```

Here I have considered the resulting `Product` type to be like this:-

```
public class Product
    {
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string UserTypeID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public List<string> ValuesIds { get; set; }
    }
```

> I don't want all attributes just some.

You haven't specified on what basis you want to fetch the `AttributeID` attribute present in `Values` node that is why I am fetching them all.

Comment: What if I was to fetch two attributes from the code above: `ValuesIds = x.Descendants("Value").Where(z =>(string)z.Attribute("AttributeID") == "CHA_SAP_MATMAS_ZZCATALOG_TYPE" )
                                         .Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("AttributeID"))
                                          .ToList()`   Can I make an array of attributes and pass it in to LINQ like this:  `ValuesIds = x.Descendants("Value").Where(z =>(string)z.Attribute("AttributeID") ==desiredIDs )`

Comment: @MaskedAfrican - Glad it helped you and you solved the other part yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visual Studio here to try, but I think you can use `Where` to achieve what you want.

```cs
XDocument.Load(file)
         .Descendants("Product")
         .Where(element => element.Attribute("ID") != null && element.Attribute("ID").Value == "thisValue")
         .ToList();
```

It will return the list of "Product" nodes with the specified ID attribute.
Don't know if it works, but something like that.